# Data upload Product , Price book and quote

Tags: data-loader, pricebook, customization, product

User has given an excel with Product code, Product Name, Product Description and Product family to upload data into Products,  Product Pricebook and New Quote.
Can anyone tell me how to upload give data and assign them to appropriate price book in salesforce using Dataloader.

Is it possible to upload and assign price book using Dataloader?

Please let me know

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible, but a multi-step process. Generally speaking, you'll want to insert your products first, then insert the product price book entries. You can use the "success" file to match the products to their prices, then simply add a column for the price book ID.

Basically, your file should look like this:

```
Product Name | Product Code | Description | Family | Price | Price Book
-------------+--------------+-------------+--------+-------+-----------------
Product 1    | 1111         |   Words     | Fam A  | 100   | PricebookIdHere
Product 2    | 2222         |   Words     | Fam B  | 200   | PricebookIdHere
Product 3    | 3333         |   Words     | Fam C  | 300   | PricebookIdHere
```

Once you import the products, you'll end up with:

```
Id | Product Name | Product Code | Description | Family | Price | Price Book
---+--------------+--------------+-------------+--------+-------+-----------------
1  | Product 1    | 1111         |   Words     | Fam A  | 100   | PricebookIdHere
2  | Product 2    | 2222         |   Words     | Fam B  | 200   | PricebookIdHere
3  | Product 3    | 3333         |   Words     | Fam C  | 300   | PricebookIdHere
```

Where 1, 2, and 3 are Salesforce IDs (abbreviated for brevity).

Simply take that success file, then insert the price book entries.

As for inserting new quotes, you might also need to insert additional records, like accounts, contacts, opportunities, etc. You basically just need to insert them in order.